# Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_Product_User_UserId' on table 'Product' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths

Tags: .net-core, ef-core-2.2

i cannot create database with ef core
error : Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_Product_User_UserId' on table 'Product' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.

this is my product class

```
   {
       public Product()
       {
       }

       public Guid UserId { get; set; }
       public Guid CategoryId { get; set; }
       public string Name { get; set; }
       public string Description { get; set; }
       public string PhotoPath { get; set; }
       public decimal Price { get; set; }

       public Category Category { get; set; }
       public User User { get; set; }
   }
```

and
this is my user class

```
    {
        public User()
        {
            Payments = new HashSet<Payment>();
            Categories = new HashSet<Category>();
            Products = new HashSet<Product>();
        }

        public string Username { get; set; }
        public Guid Password { get; set; }

        public ICollection<Payment> Payments { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Category> Categories { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }
    }
```

its mapping class

```
    {
        public ProductMap()
        {
        }

        public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Product> builder)
        {
            builder.HasKey(x => x.Id);
            builder.Property(x => x.UserId).IsRequired();
            builder.Property(x => x.CreatedDate).IsRequired();
            builder.Property(x => x.Description).HasMaxLength(500);
            builder.Property(x => x.IsActive).IsRequired();
            builder.Property(x => x.Name).HasMaxLength(500).IsRequired();
            builder.Property(x => x.PhotoPath).HasMaxLength(4000);
            builder.Property(x => x.Price).HasColumnType("decimal(10,3)").IsRequired();

            builder.HasOne(x => x.Category).WithMany(x => x.Products).HasForeignKey(x => x.CategoryId);
            builder.HasOne(x => x.User).WithMany(x => x.Products).HasForeignKey(x => x.UserId);

        }
    }
```

and i cannot create database cause error like this posts title.
what can i do?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are saying that each user has many Categories and each Category has many Products so you have to remove this line from the User class since it causing cycle path

```
public ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }
```

And also fix the last line of the Configure method:

```
builder.HasOne(x => x.User).WithMany(x => x.Categories).HasForeignKey(x => x.UserId);
```